# How do I use association proxy with classical mapping?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I read around the internet on examples using association proxies, but all of them I found were written with a *declarative* style of mapping.

Can I use them in a classical mapping? The reason why is that I'm implementing database persistence to an already existent class hierarchy and I'd like keep the db-related code in a separate file.

As an example, let's assume a model where we have an `Item` and an `Order` objects. We build a many-to-many relationship with an extra field in the association table that is, as an example, the price paid for the item:

```
item = Table('item', metadata, 
             Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
             Column('name', String), 
             Column('quantity', Integer)
             )

order = Order('order', metadata,
              Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
              Column('customer_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
             )

order_item = Table('order_item', metadata,
                   Column('order_id', Integer, ForeignKey('order.id')), 
                   Column('item_id', Integer, ForeignKey('item.id')), 
                   Column('price', Float)
                  )

# Mapping of Tables to non-orm objects
```

Let's assume I'd like to access in a nice way the items of an order as explained [in the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects) for a User-Keyword example . In the declarative way an attribute is added to the class that is an association proxy:

```
# ... Class definition ...
items = association_proxy('order_items', 'items')
```

How do I do this in a classical mapping style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-scalar-collections):

> The [`AssociationProxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.AssociationProxy) object produced by the [`association_proxy()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.association_proxy)
>   function is an instance of a [Python descriptor](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html). It is always declared
>   with the user-defined class being mapped, regardless of whether
>   Declarative or classical mappings via the [`mapper()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper) function are used.

So, just define it on the class:

```
class Order(object):
    ...
    items = association_proxy('order_items', 'items')
```

Comment: For a cleaner way (apparently) keeping in separate module the class definitions and the mappings, I ended up defining in the module where the mappers are declared, a monkey-patched attribute  to `Order` class: `Order.items = association_proxy('order_items', 'items')`, as suggested by Mike Bayer in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/Od9Gzuwj9-I) discussion on the mailing list.